# Create Table Header View

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xcode4.5

I need to create a table that got 3 columns, X rows (from database) and each column got data in it.

My first step that I struggle with is to create the 3 headers that must always appear at top of the table even when I scroll.

Am looking at the tableHeaderView property in UITableView, is there an example I can use somewhere?

Comment: HeaderView will not be visible on scrolling. Why don't you add a seperate view?

Comment: Anupdas: Add the seperate view to Table View? or seperate to the main view? e.g. a sub-view

Comment: In the mainView. If you wish to have both tableView and headerView together, create a containerView and then add both tableView and headerView to it. Its just a choice to tidy things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView * headerView;

    headerView=[[UIView alloc]init];

    //  headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);

    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);


    UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    imgview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,40);
    imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"header1.png"];

    UILabel *statuslabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10,320,20)];

    statuslabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    statuslabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // headerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];


        if(section==0)
            statuslabel.text=@"TODAY";

        else if(section==1)
            statuslabel.text=@"OLDER THAN A WEEK";

        else
            statuslabel.text=@"OLDER THAN A MONTH";


    [imgview addSubview:statuslabel];
    [headerView addSubview:imgview];
    //[headerView addSubview:statuslabel];

    return headerView;
}
```

Try this.once.....